# Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$ where $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ is a squarefree number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $n\equiv1\pmod{4}$ be a squarefree number and $p\equiv1\pmod{4n}$ be a prime number. Does there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p=x^2+ny^2$?

Answer (score -2):

How about:  p=5, n=1, x=1, y=2

Comment: I think the point was that it's a *general* question: is it true for *arbitrary* (positive) squarefree $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and *arbitrary* primes $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4n$? So giving one example where it works doesn't answer the question. In fact the result is not generally true. Some counterexamples are $n = 17$ with $p = 137$ or $953$, and also $n = 29$ with $p = 233$ or $349$. I suggest the OP look at David Cox's book "Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$", which as the title indicates is about this type of question.

Comment: Then the question should be stated as such.